# Is using Right, Left, Top, Bottom to position text bad practice?

Tags: html, css

I couldn't find an answer on Google and I'm relatively new to CSS and I'm trying to get my head around it. For example I have a image on the centre of the screen and I wanted to move the text below the image. I've used a example code below, and was wondering if it was bad practice to do this and is there a correct way to do this?

```
h2{
    position: absolute;
    padding: 5px;
    right: 70%;
    bottom: 30%; 
}
```

EDIT:

Here's the HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="images/horse4.jpg" class="slide" alt="">
    <img src="images/horse3.jpg" class="slide" alt="">
    <img src="images/horse2.jpg" class="slide" alt="">               
    <img src="images/horse1.jpg" class="slide" alt="">
    <h2>Welcome!</h2>
</div>
```

Heres the CSS:

```
.slide {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 3px;
    border-top: 2px dotted black;
    border-bottom: 2px dotted black;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a image on the centre of the screen and I wanted to move the text below the image

In that case, the text position in relation to the image will vary with different window sizes, and it might overlap or a huge gap may appear.

The best approach is to have a container that's centered, and then put both the image and text inside it. Always try to have as little irregular elements as possible. This way, instead of absolutely positioning both the image and the text, we're only doing it to one element which acts as their container and then we don't have to worry much about their positioning after we get the container right.

Here's an example:

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #aaa;
  width: 200px;
  height: 180px;
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  max-height: 150px;
}
p {
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120728235111/annoyingorange/images/b/b3/Super_mario.png" />
  <p>Hey there</p>
</div>
```

And to give a final answer to your question: **no, it's not a bad practice as long as you still have the full control of the layout**.

---

UPDATE

Here's an example slightly based on your code (thought you had the slider ready):

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #aaa;
  width: 256px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 2px dotted black;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted black;
  overflow: hidden;
} 
#slider {
  width: 512px;
  height: 256px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  transition: left 0.5s linear;
  font-size: 0;
}
#slider:hover {
  left: -256px;
}
h2 {
  margin-top: 256px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="slider">
  <img src="http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/2297/super_mario/256/paper_mario.png" class="slide" alt="">
  <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/ph03nyx/super-mario/256/Mario-Profile-icon.png" class="slide" alt="">
    </div>
  <h2>Welcome!</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm I think you're right, text is at different positions in different browsers resulting it being underneath the actual image rather than below it. I've created a pure CSS slider and given each img src a class called slider. If I create a div for container, would the text stay below the image regardless the size of the window?

Comment: Yeah, it will probably become chaotic on different screens. Why don't you just center the whole slider, put each slide into a container and use left/right offsets to control them? You can also show us your code and we'll help. Yes, as long as the image and the text are in the same box (and not positioned weirdly), they'll remain together.

Comment: I've updated the question with the code regarding slider

Comment: I thought you had the slider working. I sketched something for you. It has the container which serves as a viewport, and a slider element which is basically a narrow strip of images that scrolls on mouse hover.

Comment: I have the slider working. I used CSS3 animation but didn't think it was relevant to the question, as I just wanted to get the text to be set under the slider

Comment: Ah okay then. See how I fixed the text just by adding the top margin because absolutely position elements don't push other elements below, so I had to compensate.

Comment: I changed your code around as my slider breaks if remove the previous .slide css method I had before. The other difference is that the text is below image completely rather than ontop if it. However the text now works perfectly and doesn't get overlapped. However the text doesn't move with the image as it's resized, eg. text is always on the bottom left corner of the slider regardless of the window size.

Comment: You're welcome, glad you got it working. Next time feel free to share more of your code, so you could get more accurate answers right away.